# Добавление значения в шаблон из переменной

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

У меня есть переменная `test`

```yaml
test:
 - 10.0.0.1
 - 10.0.0.2
 - 10.0.0.3
 - 10.0.0.4
```

И есть конфиг файл куда необходимо вставить одно значение из этой переменной.
Файлов конфига должно на выходе быть 4, в каждом файле по одной строке из этой переменной test.
Разобрался как сделать, чтоб 4 файла создавались с именами ip из списка, а вот как сделать, что ip подставлялся в шаблон понять не могу.

Comment: Ну а где код, который создаёт файл с нужным именем?

Answer (score 0):

Типа такого?

```yaml
# Имя модуля:
- copy:
  # Контент означет то, что ниже можно пихать любой блок текста - он
  # будет записан в файл, который увказывается в "dest".
  # "item" - это как "i" в конструкции "for i in a b c".
  content: |
    test_ip: 111 {{ item }} 222
  dest: /tmp/ip-is-{{ item }}
  # "test" - это ваша переменная,
  # которая будет играть роль того "a b c" из комментария выше
  with_items:
    - "{{ test }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Разобрался как сделать, чтоб 4 файла создавались с именами ip из списка, а вот как сделать, что ip подставлялся в шаблон понять не могу.

В шаблон, в нужном месте просто вставить `{{ item }}`
В качестве переменной в таску должна передаваться ваша `test:`

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а мой ответ разве не делает то же самое?

Comment: @donRumata Спрашивайте, не стесняйтесь) Да, делает. Но добавить немного поясняющего текста, к вашему примеру кода, было бы не лишним.

Comment: Г о т о в о . .